# Vanguard sent 1099 for my MLP stock sale. Am I being taxed twice when I file the K1?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, investing, form-1099, schedule-k-1

I received a 1099 from Vanguard for the sale of my MLP stock. I got a K1 from the MLP. I entered both on my TaxAct program.  My question is, am I being taxed twice on the stock sale?

Answer (score 1):

The K-1 generally supersedes the 1099 for MLPs. Look for a "Sales Schedule" included with the K-1, listing the basis and sale proceeds. See also [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/96422/64920).